# How can the Disqus current username be fetched on the client side?

Tags: javascript, disqus

I would like to display the current user's Disqus username on a webpage - is there a way to get it out of the widget with JavaScript?

If not, is there a server side way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

take a look here http://disqus.com/api/docs/users/details/

you need to register your website.

responses of a simple get request is like this

```
  "code": 0,
  "response": {
    "username": "disqus_api",
    "about": "",
    "name": "disqus_api",
    "url": "",
    "isFollowing": false,
    "isFollowedBy": false,
    "profileUrl": "http://disqus.com/disqus_api/",
    "emailHash": "67f79ed8e10b74abf07a8dfe101bbab2",
    "avatar": {
      "permalink": "http://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/disqus_api.jpg",
      "cache": "http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1091/images/noavatar92.png"
    },
    "id": "1",
    "isAnonymous": false,
    "email": "example@disqus.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great - just to check, does it **require** a username/user id being given to it (because that's what I want to find out)?

Comment: you need to register your app with a set of credentials indicating you are a user, the doc says no auth required... you may have to pass in some key etc.... haven't used it myself.

Comment: I get the error "You must either provide a user or authenticate the user.", but the problem is that I want to find out who the user is. How do I do this?